# How to put a WPF app on the secondary monitor with different refresh rate?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, desktop-application

I want to start my WPF app on my secondary monitor with different refresh rate, the refresh rate of the first monitor is 60 Hz and the second monitor is 50 Hz, I used the following method to place my app on the second display:

```cs
public bool  PutToSecondaryMonitor()
{
    var secondaryScreen = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens
            .Where(s => !s.Primary).FirstOrDefault();

    if (secondaryScreen != null)
    {
        var workingArea = secondaryScreen.WorkingArea;
        this.Left = workingArea.Left;
        this.Top = workingArea.Top;
        this.Width = workingArea.Width;
        this.Height = workingArea.Height;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

But my app frame rate is always 60 Hz. Please tell me how to put a WPF app on the secondary monitor with different refresh rate?

Edit:
This is a [sample project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/10XhVu9rEBiixqrRXOGGplOr3kF8uwfWV/view?usp=sharing)

NOTE: When I run my WPF app exe file manually on the second monitor, I expect its fps to be equals of the second monitors refresh rate, but it locks in to refresh rate of the first monitor.

Comment: So your app appears in the second monitor? How you tell the refresh rate of your app?

Comment: @emoacht, Yes, I used CompositionTarget.Rendering and Stopwatch to measure the frame rate, which is accurate because if I change the frame rate of the first monitor to 50 Hz, it shows 50. I also have 50 Hz animations and videos that stutters when the monitor frame rate is not 50 Hz.

Comment: I see. I understand you set the reflesh rate of the second monitor to 50Hz and even when you place your app in that monitor, its frame rate shows 60Hz. So your actural question is the reason of this difference, right? I have no idea about it though.

Comment: Can you give us exactly a reproducing code that you use as a reference test when starting from a monitor or another? I don't reproduce what you mean.

Comment: @Simon Mourier, I added a sample project.

Comment: I do reproduce (sort of, numbers vary, I find it easier to see with a more simple less perfect :-) code https://pastebin.com/raw/WdMhiPhf I have 144hz primary & 60hz monitors) but this is expected as DXGI uses the primary monitor's vblank. Plus WPF is an oooold pre-DXGI pre-DirectComposition full-DirectX9 technology. This may be an XY problem https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem. What are you trying to solve? You can check this for latest insights on the subject. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directcomp/compositor-clock/compositor-clock

Comment: @Simon Mourier,Thank you for the great info and links, So, it seems this is impossible with WPF.